# Error when working with some time zones in MongoDB

Tags: mongodb, ubuntu-20.04

I have Ubuntu 20.04 server with MongoDB 5.0 installed and running by [official tutorial](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/install-mongodb-on-ubuntu/#install-mongodb-community-edition). I encountered problem with some timezones, for example Etc/UTC timezone. I get the error "unrecognized time zone identifier":

```
> db.data.insert({ dt: new ISODate() })
WriteResult({ "nInserted" : 1 })
> db.data.aggregate([
...     {
...         "$project": {
...             "dtTimezone": {
...                 "$dateToString": {
...                     "date": "$dt",
...                     "timezone": "Etc/UTC"
...                 }
...             }
...         }
...     }
... ])
uncaught exception: Error: command failed: {
    "ok" : 0,
    "errmsg" : "PlanExecutor error during aggregation :: caused by :: unrecognized time zone identifier: \"Etc/UTC\"",
    "code" : 40485,
    "codeName" : "Location40485"
} with original command request: {
    "aggregate" : "data",
    "pipeline" : [
        {
            "$project" : {
                "dtTimezone" : {
                    "$dateToString" : {
                        "date" : "$dt",
                        "timezone" : "Etc/UTC"
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    ],
    "cursor" : {
        
    },
    "lsid" : {
        "id" : UUID("24a0ca58-6d03-4827-b59c-4bd82ddf9976")
    }
} on connection: connection to 127.0.0.1:27017 : aggregate failed :
_getErrorWithCode@src/mongo/shell/utils.js:25:13
doassert@src/mongo/shell/assert.js:18:14
_assertCommandWorked@src/mongo/shell/assert.js:719:17
assert.commandWorked@src/mongo/shell/assert.js:811:16
DB.prototype._runAggregate@src/mongo/shell/db.js:276:5
DBCollection.prototype.aggregate@src/mongo/shell/collection.js:1058:12
@(shell):1:1
```

At the same time, when using Europe/London, everything works:

```
> db.data.aggregate([
...     {
...         "$project": {
...             "dtTimezone": {
...                 "$dateToString": {
...                     "date": "$dt",
...                     "timezone": "Europe/London"
...                 }
...             }
...         }
...     }
... ])
{ "_id" : ObjectId("611832f076340952c425ce80"), "dtTimezone" : "2021-08-14T22:17:36.349Z" }
```

I found [similar problem](https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/SERVER-41948), but the solution was to comment "processManagement.timeZoneInfo" option and use internal timezones database. I've also tried copying timezones database from the [MongoDB documentation](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/configuration-options/#mongodb-setting-processManagement.timeZoneInfo), but it doesn't make any difference:

```
curl -O https://downloads.mongodb.org/olson_tz_db/timezonedb-latest.zip
unzip timezonedb-latest.zip
rsync -a --delete timezonedb-2021a/ /usr/share/zoneinfo/
systemctl restart mongod
```

What could be the problem? Why the system database doesn't fit or work together with MongoDB?

Comment: I don't think "Etc/UTC" is a valid time zone name (in the Olsen timezone database) Use "UTC" or just skip this parameter because UTC is the default.

Comment: @WernfriedDomscheit This is correct timezone according to [this list](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_tz_database_time_zones). Query with Etc/UTC timezone are executed when using internal timezones database by commenting "processManagement.timeZoneInfo option". I can ignore Etc/UTC because it is the same as UTC, but my data has Etc/GMT+12 timezone that I cannot ignore.

Comment: What about using `+12:00` instead of `Etc/GMT+12`? It's the same, just a different format.

Comment: @WernfriedDomscheit Timezone Etc/GMT+12 equals UTC-12. This data comes from external source, I have to process it and I want to use MongoDB features to do it. I need a common solution.

Comment: Is it an option to use an external library, e.g. [moment.js](https://momentjs.com/timezone/docs/#/zone-object/offset/)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It was a bug in MongoDB, fixed in 5.0.4: https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/SERVER-59701